# i am looking for svn admin like "VisualSVN Server" for remote server?

Tags: svn, admin, visualsvn-server

i am looking for svn admin a desktop application like "VisualSVN Server" only for remote server
the svn server will run on Linux but i need the admin tool to run locally on my window matching 
i wont to be able to create user group and change security setting create new repositories
and not by writing commands

is there is a  tool like this out there?
and if so which one do  you recommend 
thanks

if it was hard to understand 
i just wants to be able to admin a subversion server remotely
thanks again

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN admin management GUI tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672431/svn-admin-management-gui-tool)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is no desktop application like i am looking for 
at list not for free

Answer (score 3):

well, creating new repositories is pretty easy if you have got access to the directories (works very nice with [tortoise svn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org) - just create a directory - create repository here from the tortoise svn menu - you're done.

On the other hand I've got no solution for creating user groups and change security settings on a linux server without the help of the almighty ssh (and the shell)

Comment: Agree on the Tortoise point, but you could probably install a Linux distro with a nice and easy remote web interface with the other stuff.. if you didn't want to get your hands dirty in the shell :)

Comment: shure thing - but I've never used one of those

Answer (score 1):

I must say I am finding it difficult to understand your question, makes me think you are not sure you want svn, but a source control/version tool that you can use on a stand alone development machine instead...(if so google Git)

Update: OK, now I understand what you want:
Here is a quick and easy [svn manager](http://svnmanager.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I think he just wants to be able to admin a subversion server remotely, including adding new users etc. And SVN runs just fine locally, if that's what he wanted to do :)

Comment: no i am not working alone on the svn and yes all i wont to be 
able to admin a subversion server remotely

Comment: okay then :) I might update later

Comment: that nice but we are not running Apache 2 or PHP 5 this is reason we prefer desktop application

Answer (score -1):

Without Apache, try [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html)